# problem regarding radius of curvature

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

I try a question to find the radius of curvature;

Find the radius of curvature of the curve $x^4+y^4=2$ at (1,1).

I try  to use formula in Cartesian form but y'' becomes zero...so using implicit form formula  I get radius of curvature as $$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}$$

Since the answer is not given in book I won't know whether my answer is correct...please tell is it correct?

Comment: I've found the same result with $y'= -x^3/y^3$ and $y''=[-3x^2(y^4+x^4)]/y^7$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$R(x_0 )=\left|\frac{((1+(y'(x_0 ))^2 )^{\frac{3}{2}}}{y'' (x_0 )}\right|$$
We have
$$4x^3 +4y^3 y' =0$$
hence
$$y'(1) =-1$$
analogously
$$12 x^2 +12 y^2 (y' )^2 +4y^3 y'' =0,$$
hence
$$y'' (1) =-6. $$
Thus
$$R(1) =-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}$$.......,.....

Answer (score 1):

Although not a proof, of course, plotting the curve with its "circle of curvature" at the point in question is often a nice way to check such a calculation.  Plotting $x^4+y^4=2$ and the circle $(x-\frac{2}{3})^2+(y-\frac{2}{3})^2=\frac{2}{9}$, I see this rather convincing picture:
[image]